# Python sckitlearn linear regression crashes on random iteration

Tags: python

I get a random error (not always at the same iteration) when running an adapted version of sckitlearn `plot_robust_fit.py`. All files needed to reproduce can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/38y8ommc9518zba/AACcwojxrIQeLSGwZ-ZdwXsNa?dl=0).

Just run `reg.py` and you most likely will get the error.

Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/geoffroy/git/sfinder_2/reg/reg.py", line 118, in <module>
  model.fit(X, acluster_y)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 141, in fit
  self.steps[-1][-1].fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ransac.py", line 301, in fit
  y_inlier_subset)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 328, in score
  return r2_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 155, in predict
  return self.decision_function(X)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 138, in decision_function
  X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 360, in check_array
  % (n_samples, shape_repr, ensure_min_samples))
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 2)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

Note that crashed samples work fine when ran separately. Even trying crashed samples all together works fine.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Could it be because of the convergence after every 300 iterations in the `TheilSenRegressor()`? It throws a warning, if you noticed.

Comment: I did notice. Weirdly, running the samples that crash separately work fine ! Even running crashing samples all together works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem comes from the Theil-Sen and RANSCAC estimators where no inliers are found. A more user friendly error has been introduced in recent version of sckitlearn. See the official github [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5533) started.